# Array para Table PHP

Tags: php, ftp, tabela-html

Eu tenho o seguinte código que conecta em um ftp e volta uma lista.
Mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que ele monte um Table com essa lista.
Alguém sabe como fazer?

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.site.com.br";
$ftp_user = "USER_FTP";
$ftp_pass = "SENHA_FTP";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "<br>$ftp_server";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

$dir = "/diretorio/";

function filecollect($dir,$filelist) {
    global $conn_id; //Retorna FTP
    $files = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$dir); //Retorna o Directory
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $isfile = ftp_size($conn_id, $file);
        if($isfile == "-1") { //É um arquivo ou diretorio?
            $filelist = filecollect($dir.'/'.$file,$filelist,$num); //Se for diretório, faça "filecollect()"
        }
        else {
            $filelist[(count($filelist)+1)] = $file; //Se não,adicione a uma arquivo para a lista
        }
    }
    return $filelist;
}

$list = filecollect($dir,$filelist);
$list = implode("<br>$ftp_server", $list);

    echo $list; 

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Sei que tem algumas falhas mas o principal é transformar esses dados em uma table.

Desde já, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Os dados voltam do ftp como array ou como objeto?

Comment: @AdrianoLuz com $list = implode("<br>$ftp_server", $list); volta uma String, se eu eu tirar o implode e colocar print_r($list) volta um array

Comment: e esse array você já tentou dar um var_dump pra ver o que tem nele? Se ele retornar um array com os campos da tabela basta dar uma foreach e montar a tabela

Answer (score 1):

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.site.com.br";
$ftp_user = "USER_FTP";
$ftp_pass = "SENHA_FTP";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    echo "<br>$ftp_server";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}

ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

$dir = "/diretorio/";

function filecollect($dir,$filelist) {
    global $conn_id; //Retorna FTP
    $files = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$dir); //Retorna o Directory
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $isfile = ftp_size($conn_id, $file);
        if($isfile == "-1") { //É um arquivo ou diretorio?
            $filelist = filecollect($dir.'/'.$file,$filelist,$num); //Se for diretório, faça "filecollect()"
        }
        else {
            $filelist[(count($filelist)+1)] = $file; //Se não,adicione a uma arquivo para a lista
        }
    }
    return $filelist;
}

$list = filecollect($dir,$filelist);


ftp_close($conn_id);
```

No HTML

```
<?php
    foreach ($list as $row)
     {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>www.site.com.br" . $row . "</td>" ;
        echo"</tr>";
     }  

?>
```

Agora está certo, para quem precisa está ai. @AdrianoLuz eu estava fazendo um foreach, mas não sei o que estava fazendo de errado que estava retornando com erro.